# union of complement sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would like to prove the following property note the sets $A, E_1 , E_2$

if $E_1^c \cap E_2^c \subseteq A^c$
then $A \subseteq E_1 \cup E_2 $

Answer (score 2):

To prove that $A\subseteq E_1\cup E_2$ we have to show that for every $x\in A$ we have $x\in E_1\cup E_2$.

Suppose not. Then $x\notin E_1\cup E_2$. So $x\notin E_1$ and $x\notin E_2$. So $x\in E_1^c\
$ and $x\in E_2^c$. Hence $x\in E_1^c\cap E_2^c$. Buy assumption we then have that $x\in A^c$, since $x\in E_1^c\cap E_2^c\subseteq A^c$.

But this is a contradiction, as $x\in A$ and $x\in A^c$ can not hold simultaneously.